# unable to copy symbols from this device

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I try to develop app for iOs with MAC OS X Mavericks, but I haven't bought a mac, I virtualize it. 
After download and install Xcode 6.1, I connect my iPad 2 on iOs 8.1 but, when my computer "copying symbol files" I've error after a long time.
The error is

> **Unable to copy symbols from this device** This device has a version of iOs different from that of this installation of Xcode. In order to
>   copy the information needed to work with this device, Xcode must be
>   run by a user with read/write access to:
>   "/Users/Lortedo/Library/developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.1
>   (12B410)/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld"

I've been in the folder and I saw the folder dyld wasn't here. So I create it manually. Too I've give the chmod 777 for all the folder mentionned.

Thanks :)
Lortedo

Answer (score 3):

Check also your harddisk. In my case, it was simply full. After deleting stuff and getting some free space, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some space on my physical harddisk, uninstall xCode, remove ~/Library/Developer/ folder, reboot my VM, empty Trash, reinstall xCode.